# Laravel Controller, save only url without domain

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller

I get from ctf0/media-manager the link to a chosen file, like
http://example.com/folder1/mypic.jpg

In my database I want only save
/folder1/mypic.jpg
because I know the domain, it's every time my one.

I need to cut the first letters flexible by counting the letters from my .env in my controller.
Maybe I want to change the domain to http://productive-example.com later, then the letters are different.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `parse_url` function if you would like:

```
$url = 'http://something.com/some/path/file.jpg';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
// "/some/path/file.jpg"
```

[PHP.net Manual - Function `parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Lagbox is correct with his answer, and I just have some additional information. if the url comes within the request, you could use the method shipped with the Request package, try to use `$request->path()` to get the path of the url